# My socket program cannot open some URLs that browsers like FireFox, IE etc can open

Tags: winapi, api, sockets

I have made the following Win32 socket program to browse web pages. I am using Mingw to avoid dependency on any runtime.

To get IP addresses, I ping urls such as `www.google.com`, `www.yahoo.com` through the command prompt and then use those ip addresses in my program. The port is of course 80.

I am able to get default pages of Google, Yahoo, etc, by using `"GET /\r\n"`. I am also able to get non-default pages, even those inside directories, such as `http://yasini.com/newsite/index.aspx` by using `"GET /newsite/index.aspx"`.

The output of the program is in the form of HTML received from the webserver, saved on the hard disk. This file is later opened in FireFox to see how the communication went.

I have made a test webpage, `http://a.domaindlx.com/trysite/hello.asp`, which I can open in FireFox. Then I ping the domain `a.domaindlx.com` and get an IP address of `66.36.238.30`. I then try to access the said page by using `"GET /trysite/hello.asp"`, but I get this in response:

> No web site is configured at this address.

I know that this response is sent by the webserver, so I was able to connect to the webserver. The problem is that the webserver is not recognizing the URL I am trying to access. I have used different webpages, both HTML and ASP, and none of them are accessible.

When trying to open a website using its IP address directly in a browser, I get the same `"No website is configured..."` error.

The basic puzzle is, why are these pages accessible through a browser such as FireFox, but not through my code? My code is essentially a browser, meaning it opens a connection with a webserver at port 80.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

WSADATA ws;

int d;
char aa[1000];
struct sockaddr_in a;
SOCKET s;
int li;

void abc(char *p)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\data.htm", "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", p);
    fclose(fp);
}

_stdcall WinMain (HINSTANCE i, HINSTANCE j, char * k, int l)
{
    d = WSAStartup(0x101, &ws);
    sprintf(aa, "WSASTARTUP = %d", d);
    abc(aa);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sprintf(aa, "SOCKET = %d", s);
    abc(aa);

    a.sin_family = AF_INET;
    a.sin_port = htons(80);
    //a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.236.145");
    a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("66.36.238.30"); //a.domaindlx.com
    //a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("206.225.85.18"); //www.domaindlx.com
    //a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("87.248.122.122"); //www.yahoo.com
    //a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("72.167.153.9"); //www.yasini.com
    d = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &a, sizeof(a));

    strcpy(aa, "GET /trysite/hello.asp\r\n");
    strcat(aa, "HTTP 1.0 \r\n\r\n");
    send(s, aa, sizeof(aa), 0);
    li = 1;

    while(li != 0)
    {
        li = recv(s, aa, 1000, 0);
        abc(aa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not save yourself a lot of bother and use the excellent libcurl library? Portable, solid and free.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.

The first problem is that there should be a space, not `\r\n`, before `HTTP 1.0`.  Without this, you are sending HTTP 0.9.

The second problem is that some IP addresses are used to host multiple sites and require sending a `Host` header.

The site that tells you "No web site is configured at this address" may work better if you add the `Host` header.   Your request to that site should look like this:

`"GET /trysite/hello.asp HTTP 1.0\r\nHost: a.domaindlx.com\r\n\r\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Many webservers (especially those that offer shared hosting) can host multiple accounts on the same physical IP, so they need to know which particular website is being requested in order to access the correct account.  To specify the target website, you need to include a `Host` header in your HTTP request.

The `Host` header is optional in HTTP 1.0 (which you are using), but is actually required by HTTP 1.1 onward, oherwise the request will fail.

Also note that when you call `send()` to send the request, you are sending the entire 1000 bytes of the `aa` buffer, which is wrong.  You need to send only what you actually filled in.

Lastly, you are not really managing the socket very well in general.  You need better error handling.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void abc(char *p, int l = -1)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\data.htm", "a+");
    if (fp)
    {
        if (l == -1) l = strlen(p);
        fwrite(p, 1, l, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE i, HINSTANCE j, char * k, int l)
{
    char aa[1000];

    WSADATA ws;
    int d = WSAStartup(0x101, &ws);
    sprintf(aa, "WSASTARTUP = %d\n", d);
    abc(aa);

    if (d == 0)
    {
        SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        sprintf(aa, "SOCKET = %d\n", s);
        abc(aa);

        if (s != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            char *host = "a.domaindlx.com";
            char *file = "/trysite/hello.asp";

            struct sockaddr_in a;
            memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));

            a.sin_family = AF_INET;
            a.sin_port = htons(80);

            struct hostent *h = gethostbyname(host);
            if (!h)
            {
                sprintf(aa, "gethostbyname(\"%s\") FAILED\n", host);
                abc(aa);
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(aa, "gethostbyname(\"%s\") TYPE = %d\n", host, h->h_addrtype);
                abc(aa);

                if (h->h_addrtype == AF_INET)
                {
                    a.sin_addr = * (struct in_addr*) h->h_addr;
                    sprintf(aa, "gethostbyname(\"%s\") IP = %s\n", host, inet_ntoa(a.sin_addr));
                    abc(aa);

                    d = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &a, sizeof(a));
                    sprintf(aa, "CONNECT = %d\n", d);
                    abc(aa);

                    if (d == 0)
                    {
                        sprintf(aa,
                            "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                            "Host: %s\r\n"
                            "Connection: close\r\n"
                            "\r\n",
                            file, host);

                        char *p = aa;
                        int t = strlen(aa);
                        int li;

                        do
                        {
                            li = send(s, p, t, 0);
                            if (li < 1)
                                break;

                            p += li;
                            t -= li;
                        }
                        while (t > 0);

                        if (t != 0)
                        {
                            abc("SEND FAILED\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            abc("SEND OK\n");

                            do
                            {
                                li = recv(s, aa, sizeof(aa), 0);
                                if (li < 1)
                                    break;

                                abc(aa, li);
                            }
                            while (true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            closesocket(s);
        }

        WSACleanup();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I strongly suggest you get a packet sniffer, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).  Then you can see EXACTLY what webbrowsers (or any other socket app) is actually sending and receiving.  Then you can match that in your code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not following the protocol correctly.  You want `GET /trysite/hello.asp HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`  See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for the full spec.

Comment: I have tried this, got the following message from webserver: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0 Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2011 19:42:59 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 111 X-Cache: MISS from linto Connection: close No web site is configured at this address. Content-Length: 111 X-Cache: MISS from linto Connection: close No web site is configured at this address. Content-Length: 111 X-Cache: MISS from linto Connection: close

Comment: Ok, I got it working, the correct format is: "GET http://a.domaindlx.com/trysite/my.htm HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n". It means full url including protocol-name and domain-name. In the working code I have to remove the strcat line and replace the strcpy line with this: strcpy(aa, "GET http://a.domaindlx.com/trysite/my.htm HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"); Rest of the code is fine. Thanks luke for pointing me towards the right direction.

Comment: I believe that syntax is generally intended for use by proxies, though it may be acceptable for all types of clients.  Most clients add a Host: header to the request instead; e.g. `GET /trysite/my.htm HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: a.domaindlx.com\r\n\r\n`